# nsmutableArray replacing element with last added object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

After adding new element in mutableArray previously added element(Fetched from dictionary) is also replace with newly added element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_ContentArray count]; i++){

    if ([[[_ContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"video"]) {

        NSString *videoUrl = [[_ContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"url"];

        NSString *videoName = [[_ContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"];


        [_videoContentDict setValue:videoUrl  forKey:@"url"];
        [_videoContentDict setValue:videoName forKey:@"title"];

        [_videoArray addObject:_videoContentDict];


        NSLog(@"%@%%",_videoArray);

    }

    }
```

HERE - 
_videoContentDict is an mutableDictionary
_videoArray is an mutableArray

Comment: Have you allocated memory for both? Why You are using dictionary to add value in another array? You can use NSObject for storing value.

Comment: You on,y have one dictionary. You are repeatedly adding that dictionary to `videoArray`. When you change the dictionary, that change will be reflected at all elements in the array as all elements are references to the same dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get each time old object with new object in to the `NSMutableArray`. because you are allocated `NSMutableDictionary` outside the for loop.

So make your `NSMutableDictionary` alloc init in side the for loop like following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_ContentArray count]; i++){

    if ([[[_ContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"video"]) {

        _videoContentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        NSString *videoUrl = [[_ContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"url"];

        NSString *videoName = [[_ContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"];


        [_videoContentDict setValue:videoUrl  forKey:@"url"];
        [_videoContentDict setValue:videoName forKey:@"title"];

        [_videoArray addObject:_videoContentDict];


        NSLog(@"%@%%",_videoArray);

    }

   }
```